# SQL data returned in a comma-delimited list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Here are my tables:

```
-----------------------------------------
Hotels
-----------------------------------------
HotelID | HotelName
-----------------------------------------


-----------------------------------------
HotelImages
-----------------------------------------
HotelImageID | HotelID | Filename
-----------------------------------------
```

I'd like to create a SELECT statement that will return the data like so:

```
HotelID | HotelName | Images
-----------------------------------------
1 | Hotel1 | Image1,Image2,Image3
2 | Hotel2 | Image4,Image5,Image6
```

How can I modify my query to do this? I have:

```
SELECT H.HotelID, H.HotelName, '' AS Images
FROM Hotels H
```

I know I can use COALESCE to create a comma-delimited list:

```
DECLARE @Images varchar(500)
SELECT @Images = COALESCE(@Images + ',', '') + CAST(Filename AS varchar(100)) FROM HotelImages WHERE HotelID = 1
SELECT @Images
```

But I don't know how to integrate that into my current query so that the list can be returned with the rest of the hotel data.

I should mention I'm using SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Can I ask you why you want SQL to format the result? What is reading/using the result set returned from this query, maybe that would be better suited to to formatting the data? If you return the Images as fields using the pivot command then format it after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is SQL 2000 you options are somewhat limited. You can't use FOR XML PATH or recursive CTEs

Also the COALESCE trick only works for stuffing a comma delimited list for single hotel. Not all of them.

Honestly you're better off doing this in the client. But if that can't be done (certain Report Apps that-which-must-not-be-named come to mind) you can do the following.

Note the number of times the loop process is equal to maximum number of files associated with a hotel. This is much better than setting up a loop for each hotel (e.g. calling a UDF from the select clause).

```
DECLARE @foo table ( HotelID int , lastID int , FileNameList varchar(8000))

INSERT INTO @Foo 

SELECT
    start.HotelID,
    start.firstID ,
    id.FileName 

FROM
    (SELECT 
        HotelID,
        min(HotelImageID ) firstID
    from 
        HotelImages


    group by HotelID) start
    INNER JOIN HotelImages hi
    ON start.firstID = hi.HotelImageID 


WHILE @@RowCount <> 0 
BEGIN

    UPDATE @foo
    SET 
        FileNameList = FileNameList + ',' + FileName
        lastID  = Xnext.nextID
    FROM 
        @foo f
        INNER JOIN HotelImages hi
        ON f.HotelID = id.HotelID
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 

            id.HotelID,
            min(HotelImageID ) nextID
        from HotelImages hi
              inner join @foo f
              on f.HotelID = id.HotelID
        where id.HotelImageID  > f.lastid


        group by id.HotelID) Xnext

        ON Xnext.nextID = id.HotelImageID 



END 

SELECT 
    h.HotelID 
    h.HotelName,
    f.FileNameList
FROM
    Hotels h
    INNER JOIN @foo f
    ON h.hotelId = f.HotelId
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT H.HotelID, H.HotelName, 
Images = (select COALESCE(HotelImageID + ',', '') 
            FROM HotelImages 
            WHERE HotelID = H.id)
FROM Hotels H
```

Comment: Tried that, but got this error message: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

COALESCE does not do what you suggest.  It returns the first non-NULL value from a list.  It does not aggregate values across rows. (Although I agree that it *sounds* like it does the aggregation).

SQL Server does not have direct support for string-concatenation aggregation (MySQL, for instance, has GROUP_CONCAT).  I've seen several solutions posted that provide this kind of functionality, but I'm pretty sure they're for SQL-2005 and above.  Google (or search here) on "GROUP_CONCAT FOR SQL SERVER".